# restrict IE8 to get css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

In my site, I have a css file with all the media queries. how can i use a condition not to use that file if its IE8? i am using html and jquery. IE8 does not support media queries. so i want to restrict IE8 to get that media-queries.css file. but all other browsers should get it. It can be jquery or javascript.

the css is included in the head:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/style.css" />
    <!-- dont want this only in IE8 and bellow -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/media-queries.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Conditional comments http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx All other browsers just see a comment, IE sees an `if`

Comment: ^ post that as an answer.

Comment: @PaulS. your question was a bit confusing but i got it <!--[if lt IE 9]> please mark my answer as correct, all the rest didn't get that.

Comment: I have tried this before; but then the other browsers also dont get it. like firefox, chrome, safari, etc. they take it as a commented block.

Comment: @LiadLivnat I get the appeal of rep, but that's rather excessive calling that much attention while thrashing all other posts en masse.

Comment: @LiadLivnat Not to mention, your answer is the only one that is completely incorrect.

Comment: If `media-queries.css` only contains media queries, it'll be ignored by < IE9 anyway, but a conditional comment will save you the HTTP request.

Comment: Or you could make IE 8 parse media queries : http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/style.css" />
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/media-queries.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The code means: *if greater than IE8 take notice of this html*. Only IE reads these queries so by adding `<!-->` and `<!--` other browsers just see two comments with a link to a CSS file in between.